# "Apple Watch Only" apps not showing on Apple Watch when using Configuration Profile on linked iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-watch, apple-configurator, configuration-profiles, apple-watch.app

The **Breathe, Heart, Stocks, Walkie-Talkie, and Workout** apps are not showing up on my Apple Watch.

I know this is because I have a configuration profile on my iPhone with an app whitelist only configuration. When the profile is removed, the apps appear on the watch. This is done through inputing the app bundle ID. The Activity app which is on both the Apple Watch and iPhone is appearing on my Apple Watch since I was able to add it to the whitelisted apps.

I use Apple Configurator 2 to provision the iPhone. I cannot find any app bundle IDs for any of the listed above Apple Watch apps.

I have done lots of troubleshooting and have not come to any conclusions.

Can anyone offer me some suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, it's certainly an interesting one. Haven't come across this before. Hopefully we get an answer for you!

Comment: That said, can you also please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/365847/edit) your question to clarify the troubleshooting you've done? Otherwise we won't have the full picture and may end up suggesting things you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find the app bundle IDs for the apps I mentioned in the question. Without the app bundle IDs you cannot add the apps to the whitelist. My solution to this issue was to enable blacklist mode for apps instead. This caused the missing apps to appear. Not able to use app whitelist mode, but this was the next best thing.